# Joomla content edit call stack and URL routing

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3.x CMS. I have SEO enabled. I am also routing the URL so that article IDs, category and category IDs are hidden. Hence a typical article with an alias of `my-alias` will have the URL: `http://localhost/my-alias`. I am doing this routing in a system plugin in method `onAfterInitialise()`. All aliases in the system are ensured to be unique. Now when an article is being viewed, anyone with access will see an edit URL as follows: `http://localhost/my-alias?task=article.edit&return=someValidToken`. This too is routed properly to the actual article to be edited.

When viewing an article, the user/browser does not see the article ID (as desired). When editing, the user/browser sees the article ID (not what I want). That is, when user clicks the edit link, browser loads the edit form and user sees the following URL: `http://localhost/edit-article?view=form&layout=edit&a_id=1002&return=someValidToken`, where 1002 is the article ID.

Following is a code snippet from `onAfterInitialise()`:

```
if (isset($query['task']) && $query['task']=='article.edit') {
    // TODO Hide this change from the user/browser
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', 'form');
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('layout', 'edit');
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('a_id', $articleId);
}
else {
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('option', 'com_content');
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', 'article');
    JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('id', $articleId);
}
JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('Itemid', 111); // map to dummy item in hidden menu with alias edit-article
```

I would like to know how to solve this. An understanding of the call flow through the Joomla framework will help.

Comment: do you mean is making your url `/my-alias` without the query string `?task=article.edit&return=someValidToken` ?

Comment: I lost 50 points due to an earlier bounty on this question. I thought points will be refunded if there are no suitable answers!